# objective-c 2.0 Duplicate interface definition for class when defining private methods

Tags: objective-c, object, methods

i try to define simple private methods and properties in class but it gives me:

```
Duplicate interface definition for class 'FBViewController'
```

this is the .m file :

```
#import "FBAppDelegate.h"
#import "FBViewController.h"
#import<FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "FBLoginViewController.h"
    @interface FBAppDelegate()
        @property (strong,nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;
        @property (strong, nonatomic) FBViewController *mainController;
        -(void) showLoginView;
    @end


    @implementation FBAppDelegate
    @synthesize navController = _navController,
    mainController =_mainController;

    ...
    ...

    @end
```

and this is the *.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface FBAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

**UPDATE**
added the import files

**SOLVED **
in FacebookSDK there is FBViewController.h already

Comment: i dont know too much about @calss because it's too confusing. Did u tried with import  "FBViewController" ??

Comment: `@class` in the .h file is not needed (because you don't use it). But you have to import the `FBViewController.h` in the .m file.  Answering to the above comment: `@class` is a forward declaration. You just say that a class exists, and the compiler should not complain about unknown type.

Comment: don't know if it matters, but it should be FBAppDelegate ()

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is

```
Duplicate interface definition for class 'FBViewController'
```

And you are looking to class called FBAppDelegate. Try reading the error message again, it may help.